# Redirect a url to a local server

Tags: node.js, redirect

Is there any way to redirect a url to a local server?

Like `http://example.com/1.js` to `http://localhost/1.js`, without changing `hosts` file, using `node js`.

Comment: If u have apache server running in local,,it can be done by configuring proxy in apache server, is that what u need

Comment: Dave, ya that will do, but how a proxy can be configured so that it will catch urls and redirect them to localhost?

Comment: which Operating System you are using

Answer (score 0):

To configure apache on windows, refer this link [proxy on windows](https://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDOC11/configure-apache-httpd-as-a-reverse-proxy-modproxy.html)

To configure apache on UBUNTU, refer this links 
[Apache2 reverse proxies](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Apache2_reverse_proxies) 
  [Apache proxy on ubuntu](http://boriskuzmanovic.wordpress.com/2006/10/20/apaches-proxypass-on-ubuntu/)

In below code, 
if i visit  localhost/http-bind.  it will hit localhost:5280/http-bind/

```
ProxyPass /http-bind http://localhost:5280/http-bind/
```

Comment: Will it work for http://google.com, to redirect to http://localhost? Means global urls